# How does gmail show "action" without email markup present?

Tags: email, gmail, html-email, markup

This is the email I received from flipkart - https://gist.github.com/syst3mw0rm/b5fe25633aed78865a0b

When I check the above email using markup tester - https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester

it says, it has no structured data. i.e, it has no email markup in it. How does gmail show "View Order" action then?

Here's the screenshot showing it - https://www.evernote.com/l/ANzpEoWx0gpOOIdRXSupqzqmiWlr0gS7RHc

Comment: hi aamir did you found solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an integration from Gmail that is placed in the email. See this link for how to do it: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/order

This data is usually read at the server level and is not displayed in the source shown in the email received.  So looking through that you would not see the markup, etc that called this button.

Here is a link for other available actions that can be done in gmail - https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action

Also found this great answer as well: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47674/new-view-order-button-in-google-mail

> It's based on a initiative called Schema.org. Google announced this
>   feature for Gmail in May 2013:
>   http://gmailblog.blogspot.dk/2013/05/take-action-right-from-inbox.html
>
> Quotes from the post (emphasis and linkifying mine):
>
> Email is an important part of how we get things done -- from planning
>   an event with friends to organizing that family vacation to Costa
>   Rica. And today, getting those things done is getting a little easier
>   with new quick action buttons in Gmail, designed to help you tackle
>   your digital to-do’s as quickly as possible. ... and ...
>
> These buttons appear next to certain types of messages in your inbox
>   and let you take action on an email without ever having to open it.
>   For example, you can RSVP to your friend's party invitation or rate
>   that restaurant you went to last night all right from the inbox.
>   You’ll be checking things off that to-do list in no time. ... and ...
>
> If you are a developer and want to add actions to your emails, check
>   out http://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas to learn more.

Comment: I know about schema.org and my question is, why do I not see schema.org tag in this email. I looked up code for 5-6 services having such buttons in my gmail and majority of those had schema.org elements in their email. And what do you mean by "data is usually read at the server level"? Email once delivered may not contact server at all.

Comment: After the email passes the filtering process and hits the IP, it then hits a pre-processor that processes the code to decide what coding is accepted, etc to ensure the email client is able to safely and securely display the email.

Comment: Does that mean preprocessor removed the markup? Ultimately, what's received by the browser (original email) is rendered. How can the final code received by browser not have the markup?